# Where to put this code in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I put the following code in every controller under public `function index()`. As of now I have 3 controllers and it will increase until my website is finish. I need the code below in all pages (i.e. views).

```
$type = $this->input->post('type');
$checkin = $this->input->post('sd');
$checkout = $this->input->post('ed');
```

My question is where can I put the code above in just one location so it will be available on all pages (i.e. views) and avoid putting it in every controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own controller (for example MY_cotroller) extending CI_controller, put shared code there, and then your three controllers should extend MY_controller.
You can then call it wherever you need it (or even put it to constructor if you need it everywhere).

Here's the sample I promised (assuming you have default codeigniter settings)

in *core* folder create file named MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

   protected $type;
   protected $checkin;
   protected $checkout;

   protected $bar;

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->i_am_called_all_the_time();
    }

    private function i_am_called_all_the_time() {
       $this->type = $this->input->post('type');
       $this->checkin = $this->input->post('sd');
       $this->checkout = $this->input->post('ed');
    }

    protected function only_for_some_controllers() {
       $this->bar = $this->input->post('bar');
    }

    protected function i_am_shared_function_between_controllers() {
       echo "Dont worry, be happy!";
    }
}
```

then create your controller in controllers folder

```
class HelloWorld extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function testMyStuff() {
       // you can access parent's stuff (but only the one that was set), for example:
       echo $this->type;

       //echo $this->bar; // this will be empty, because we didn't set $this->bar
    }

    public function testSharedFunction() {
       echo "some complex stuff";
       $this->i_am_shared_function_between_controllers();
       echo "some complex stuff";
    }
}
```

then for example, another controller:

```
class HappyGuy extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->only_for_some_controllers(); // reads bar for every action
    }

    public function testMyStuff() {
       // you can access parent's stuff here, for example:
       echo $this->checkin;
       echo $this->checkout;

       echo $this->bar; // bar is also available here
    }

    public function anotherComplexFunction() {
       echo "what is bar ?".$this->bar; // and here
       echo "also shared stuff works here";
       $this->i_am_shared_function_between_controllers();
    }
}
```

Those are just examples, of course you won't echo stuff like this, but pass it to view etc., but I hope it's enough for illustration. Maybe someone comes with better design, but this is what I've used a few times.

Comment: hi, i'm new to codeigniter and i don't understand how to code this. may be a sample code would help. thanks

Comment: Sadly I am writing this from my phone so it's hard, but if you search 'extending ci_controller', it should guide you through that step.

Comment: Then each of your controllers only extend the MY_Controller. Sorry but can't help further. If there is no answer later I will gladly post sample code.

Comment: heres a link for the manual page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html, see the "Extending Core Class" part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example a main view file, and you need that code on every page, then I suggest you put in the main view file (view/index.php)

I think, with @KadekM answer, you should call a function every time in every controller, because you sad, you want this code in every controllers every function.

Answer (score 0):

id suggest , adding it to a library and then auto load the library so that each and every page on your website can access the same.

for autoloading reffer : [autoload in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)